# Access session data from another thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a issue here. In my web app i have a page that starts another thread for time consuming task. In this new thread i have a call to one of my architecture methods **(Inside another project - an architecture project)**. The problem is: in one of this methods i access a **HttpContext.Current.Session** field. But when i launch the application a exception is thrown saying that this object (**HttpContext.Current.Session**) has a null reference. How could i set the context of the new thread the same as HttpApplication context in order to access **HttpContext.Current.Session** ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a number of things to consider here.

If your thread has a lifetime equal to that of the page and you need a good deal of random access to the [`HttpSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx), then you should get the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) from the call that creates the background thread using the static [`Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx).

Once you have that, you can pass that to your thread and then when you need access to *anything* on the [`HttpContextBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) associated with the request (and this includes the session), you can call the [`Post` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) on the `SynchronizationContext` that you passed to your thread to get values (or set them):

```
// From thread servicing request.
var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

// Run the task
Task t = Task.Run(() => {
    // Do other stuff.
    // ...

    // The value to get from the session.
    string sessionValue = null;

    // Need to get something from the session?
    sc.Post(() => {
        // Get the value.
        sessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionValue"];
    }

    // Do other stuff.
    // ...
});
```

It's important to do this, as access to the `HttpContextBase` (and anything associated with it) is *not* thread-safe and is tied to the thread (well, the context) processing the request.

Note that the `Post` method doesn't block, so code that comes after the call to `Post` (i.e. the lines after `// Do other stuff.`) should be independent of the delegate that's passed to `Post`.  If the code that comes after is dependent and you need to wait for the call to complete before continuing, then you can call the [`Send` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx); it has the same signature and will block until the code in the delegate is executed.

That said, if you want just *read-only* access to the values, then it's better to get them *before* you call your code, and then access them in your background thread:

```
// Get the values needed in the background thread here.
var values = {
    SessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionValue"];
};

// Run the task
Task t = Task.Run(() => {
    // Do other stuff.
    // ...

    // Work with the session value.
    if (values.SessionValue == ...)

    // Do other stuff.
    // ...
});
```

If your thread is going to continue to process after the request is serviced, then you *only* have read-only state, and you *have* to capture it before you start the thread.  Once the request is serviced, even though the session lives, it's a logical concept; depending on the provider for the session state (session state manager, SQL Server, etc.), the object could be hydrated every time a new request comes in.

You'd also have to deal with session timeout issues, you wouldn't know if the session even *exists* at the point you want to access it.

Comment: I've updated the post with the following info: The method that gets called inside the new thread is inside another project (a class library one). This approach wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: No, you have a design issue at this point.  You should provide async methods which accept a `SynchronizationContext` to call back on in the event you need access to the `HttpContext`.  Generally speaking, using the `HttpContextBase` through the `Current` property should be avoided in asynchronous operations if you can avoid it.  As you can see, you have to thread the synchronization context through the entire call stack in order to access those variables from another thread.

Comment: It seems that you assume that sc.Post executes immediately. This is true in "legacy" asp.net where it does indeed execute immediately, however, the idea of Post is that it may as well execute on the threadpool. So I would not rely on the session value in the "do other stuff" part.

Comment: @Marcus A simple oversight.  Corrected by adding the explanation of the differences between `Post` and `Send` in the second paragraph after the first code sample, as well as when you would want to use each.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the current context into the child thread, the problem is that it is dependent on the parent context. If the parent context dies, then your thread will no longer have access to the context & it will cause problems.

One solution is to clone the parent context, then use the clone in the thread. That way, if the parent thread disposes, the thread will continue to work & have access to all the context goodies.

```
HttpContext ctx = ThreadingFixHttpContext();
Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    HttpContext.Current = ctx;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = ctx.User;
    var test = HttpContext.Current.Session["testKey"];
}));
newThread.Start();
```

This should also work with the Task.Run() way too. The methods that do the work:

```
    private static Object CloneObject(Object Source)
    {
        MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter Formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        Formatter.Serialize(Stream, Source);
        Stream.Position = 0;
        object Clone = (object)Formatter.Deserialize(Stream);
        Stream.Close(); Stream.Dispose();
        return Clone;
    }

    public static System.Web.HttpContext ThreadingFixHttpContext()
    {
        //If this method is called from a new thread there is issues holding httpContext.current (which is injected from parent thread in AniReturnedPaymentsFetch.ascx.cs
        //The parent http current will die of its own accord (because it is from a different thread)
        //So we clone it into thread current principal. 
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ThreadIdentity =
            (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)CloneObject(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);

        //Then create a new httpcontext using the parent's request & response, so now the http current belongs to this thread and will not die.
        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        var ctx = new System.Web.HttpContext(request, response);
        ctx.User = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(ThreadIdentity);
        return ctx;
    }
```

Comment: Type 'System.Web.HttpContext' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: This is currently used in an enterprise environment, so it definitely works. I never encountered your error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the session from within a thread, but you could share your data using: `HttpRuntime.Cache`

There are a few things to keep in mind though: unlike session, cache do expire. Also the cache is shared between all web users.