# Passing data from .aspx file to .ashx file using Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

Actually I am trying to send data from .aspx to .ashx file. I am using Session in .aspx and trying to get value of session in .ashx but it is showing exception:: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Here is my code :-

.aspx code

```
[WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
public static string SetId(string Id)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["MId"] = Id.ToString(); Console.Write(" ");
    string session = HttpContext.Current.Session["MId"].ToString(); // Here I am getting value

    //string session = HttpContext.Current.Session["MId"].ToString();
    //BatchReadEmails.EmailProperties session = new BatchReadEmails.EmailProperties();
    //session.MailId = Id.ToString();

    return "Ok";
}
```

I am getting value in string session.
.ashx code:-

```
 public class ChangeLogHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
            {

                public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                HttpRequest request = context.Request;
                HttpResponse response = context.Response;
                  string session = "";

                if (context.Session["MId"] != null)
                    session = context.Session["MId"].ToString();
                else
                    session = "Hello India";


            }
            }
```

Here it is showing session = "Hello India"

My Question:-

1. Is there any way to send data from .aspx to .ashx file??
2. I checked so many links all are using if for null but I already check in .aspx file it is showing value there but showing null in .ashx file Why?? (For exceptional cases we can use/ write if condition but I already checked string session has value.

Am I missing something?? Thanks

These are the links I already used:-

[How to access Session in .ashx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447196/how-to-access-session-in-ashx-file#)
[Accessing context session variables in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540455/accessing-context-session-variables-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I notice you're using a webmethod in the page to set the session value. Does it work if you set the session value to something in the main Page_Load?

Comment: Yes, It is coming,If I define in Page_Load

Comment: Are you sure the webmethod is executed before the call to the ashx?

Comment: Yes it is executed. And am using 'session' variable to check whether it is containing something or not.

Comment: Can you update the ashx code - the code shown doesn't compile (as the code is just in the class body). See my comment about SSCCE - its important if you want constructive help and people not getting frustrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's working.I did these changes:-

Instead of

```
[WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
```

I put

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

But Both are the correct way.

And I include 
`async: false` in my ajax call. (I think before setting the session it was trying to read it)

Answer (score 3):

In the aspx you're adding `Session["MId"]`. In the ashx you're reading `Session["MailId"]`.

Make the keys you're using the same. (ie either `MId` or `MailId`, but not both).

Would suggest you define a constant to define this value since it's shared, then you can avoid such problems.

Comment: M sorry but both are same acutally I tried so many ways so at last it as MailId. But it is same there

Comment: Well then make sure the code you show as having the problem is the code you're actually using that has the problem, not something else that has other issues. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for what is best to post to these sites.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me well

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MailId"] = "somemail@address.com";
        Response.Redirect("Handler.ashx");
    }
```

/// Code in ashx

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {

        string sessionValue = context.Session["MailId"].ToString();
        context.Response.Write(sessionValue);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I like to know whether u accessing handler from an ajax call or not

Comment: He's already using `IRequiresSessionState` which will do the job (and allow read-write access to session).