# Generically timeout a function call (without Task/CancellationToken)

Tags: .net, vb.net

For user experience reasons I can't afford to allow long running methods.
All methods running longer than X milliseconds are enqueued to a background process (which is not the topic here).

I am looking for a generic mecanism to force the execution of a method/function within a determined timelapse.

So far I came to the following solution :

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

    Public Function CallWithTimeOut(Of T)(timeOut As Integer, dlg As [Delegate]) As T
        Dim ret As T

        Dim th As Thread

        th = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub() ret = DirectCast(dlg.DynamicInvoke(), T)))

        th.Start()
        th.Join(timeOut)
        If th.IsAlive Then
            th.Abort()
            Throw New TimeoutException
        End If

        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Function testStr(ByVal str As String) As String
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Return str
    End Function

    Private Function testInTimeOut(timeOut As Integer, ByVal str As String) As String
        Return CallWithTimeOut(Of String)(timeOut, Function() testStr(str))
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine(testInTimeOut(2000, "plopTimeOut")) ' OK
        Console.WriteLine(testInTimeOut(1000, "plopTimeOut")) ' Exception

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

It works quite well but I'm facing some problems :

- delegate.DynamicInvoke is known for not being performant
- the code inside the delegate being called dynamically, it looses all the context example when used on a webApi or a webForm project HttpContext.Current becomes null

Does anyone has an idea on how to improve my CallWithTimeOut function ?

Note : I don't want to use Tasks/cancellationToken approach since I can't pass token to the method, and it would still be running even after the timeout

Edit :

Solved performance issue by replacing [Delegate] with Func.Invoke()

```
Public Function CallWithTimeOut(Of T)(timeOut As Integer, fnc As Func(Of T)) As T
    Dim ret As T

    Dim th As Thread

    th = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub() ret = fnc.Invoke()))

    th.Start()
    th.Join(timeOut)
    If th.IsAlive Then
        th.Abort()
        Throw New TimeoutException
    End If

    Return ret
End Function
```

Still can't solve the 2nd issue

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is dangerous and should only ever be called when trying to forcibly exit your entire application. You should find graceful ways to end threads or use complete processes if you want to force things to shut down.

Comment: [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) has a constructor that allows to specify a Timeout (don't follow the code there, see the Remarks section). Can also be set using the `CancelAfter()` method (to cause a reset, if needed. In case the CTS has not been canceled yet).

Comment: @Jimi I know it, but if the cancelationtoken is not handled within the called code,  the actual execution of the method will not be cancelled at all. Your application will stop waiting for the result, but the actual work will still be going.

Comment: That's why you pass the CTS Token around and use it to verify whether the operation has been canceled. Call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` to spread the *bad news* to all copies of the Token.

Comment: @Jimi I am looking for something generic. The delegate method doesn't know how to handle a cancellationtoken, so if there is no mechanism to handle the *bad news* it will continue to run. It is good when you are in an iteration, each time you check if the token is cancelled before continuing or stopping. But if you only have one instruction that take 2 minutes to complete you can't re-check the cancellation status after its end. if your token is cancelled at 1 millisecond after the start you are screwed.

Comment: What kind of operation that takes 2 minutes? Async ops all accept a CacellationToken as argument: `Stream ReadAsync`, `FileStream.WriteAsync`, `SqlConnection.OpenAsync` etc. Your own procedure? Then you have all means to check whether `IsCancellationRequested` has been set. The problem is, you're stuck with Threads. Move on to Tasks. Standard delegates or Lambdas handle cancellations gracefully.

Comment: @Jimi 2 mins is just an example, even 30 seconds is a bit much for a user to wait after clicking a button. Working with legacy code, if there is somewhere a call to a stored proc that takes ages to process SqlCommand.ExecuteReader is not async, and doesn't take a cancellation token as an argument

Comment: [SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync) (you also have  transactions, in `IAsyncResult` style). I understand. You have existing code, refactoring to Tasks is neither as simple as it looks like on paper nor a short-term *task* :). But, IMO, the time needed to solve all possible implementation bugs derived from the direct use of Threads (especially when data exchange is involved) is not worth it, when you have a well-established alternative that supports these operation internally.

Comment: This is not possible to do in a generic way - without cooperation from the called function (that is, `CancellationToken`), it's not possible to guarantee that a timeout will be honored by the called function. Aborting threads randomly can lead to resource leaks (no chance to clean up resources) and other instabilities. It's only possible to guarantee that the caller stops listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with everybody saying that using Tasks is better and CancellationToken, but rewriting all the legacy code in order to comply would be too time consuming.

I actually found a solution to my context problem thanks to [Access session data from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036928/access-session-data-from-another-thread)

So here is my final solution :

```
Public Function CallWithTimeOut(Of T)(timeOut As Integer, dlg As Func(Of T), Optional ByVal ctx As System.Web.HttpContext = Nothing) As T
    Dim ret As T

    Dim th As Thread

    th = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub()
                                        If Not ctx Is Nothing Then
                                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current = ctx
                                        End If
                                        ret = dlg.Invoke()
                                    End Sub))

    th.Start()
    th.Join(timeOut)
    If th.IsAlive Then
        th.Abort()
        Throw New TimeoutException
    End If

    Return ret
End Function
```